# In a ruby file, how can i get another ruby file's result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to use in my ruby file another ruby file's result. For example, if the other file has a print "example" line, i would like to use the string "example" in my original ruby file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'd like to see your code. It helps us see what you've tried and allows us to correct your mistake without guessing about what it could be.

Comment: Why would you need to do this for rails? anyway you should probably just use `require`

Comment: So - am i reading this right that you want to run the ruby code held in another file, and then access the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
the_output = `ruby my_other_file.rb`
```

notice that these are backticks, not regular quotes

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried, but it didn't work for me. I have two ruby files in a folder, teszt1.rb and teszt2.rb, teszt1.rb has one line: print "example", teszt2.rb has one line: output = `ruby teszt1.rb` . But i got an error "No such file or directory - ruby teszt1.rb"

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. Try using the full path to teszt1.rb and see if that makes a difference

Comment: @Esad, you need to show us a minimal example of your code that demonstrates what you're trying to do. Explaining a problem doesn't do nearly as well as actually showing code that demonstrates it.

Comment: I have 2 ruby files in C:\Ruby22\bin. teszt1.rb contains this:

#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# encoding: UTF-8

the output = `ruby teszt2.rb`

teszt2.rb contains this:

print "0"

I open cmd, go to C:\Ruby22\bin, and type ruby teszt1.rb, i got an error:
No such file or directory - ruby teszt2.rb. What am i doing wrong? Thank you guys for helping.

Comment: I tried it on a different computer, and it worked perfectly. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can also require the first file in the second one and use the result

test.rb

```
@a = 1+1
```

test2.rb

```
require "test.rb"
c = @a + 1
```